# SPI Extra Clock Cycle over communication between STM32 Nucleo L432KC and MAX31865 ADC

Tags: c++, clock, spi, adc, mbed

The setup that I'm working with is a Nucleo L432KC connected to 8 different MAX31865 ADCs to get temperature readings from RTDs (resistive thermal devices). Each of the 8 chip selects is connected to its own pin, but the SDI/SDO of all chips are connected to the same bus, since I only read from one at a time (only 1 chip select is enabled at a time). For now, I am using a 100 ohm base resistor in the Kelvin connection, not an RTD, just to ensure an accurate resistance reading. The read from an RTD comes from calling the function rtd.read_all(). When I read from one and only one RTD, I get an accurate reading and an accurate SPI waveform (pasted below):

[correct SPI reading for 1 ADC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWWCq.jpg)
(yellow is chip enable, green is clock, blue is miso, purple is mosi)

However, when I read from 2 or more sequentially, the SPI clock for some reason gains an additional unwanted cycle at the start of the read that throws off the transmitted values. It's been having the effect of shifting the clock to the right and bit-shifting my resistance values to the left by 1.

[Logic analyzer reading of SPI; clock has additional cycle at start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3KoR.jpg)

What could be causing this extra clock cycle? I'm programming in C++ using mbed. I can access the SPI.h file but I can't see the implementation so I'm not sure what might be causing this extra clock cycle at the start. If I need to add the code too, let me know and I'll edit/comment.

rtd.read_all() function:

```
uint8_t MAX31865_RTD::read_all( )
{
  uint16_t combined_bytes;

  //SPI clock polarity/phase (CPOL & CPHA) is set to 11 in spi.format (bit 1 = polarity, bit 0 = phase, see SPI.h)
  //polarity of 1 indicates that the SPI reading idles high (default setting is 1; polarity of 0 means idle is 0)
  //phase of 1 indicates that data is read on the first edge/low-to-high leg (as opposed to phase 0,
  //which reads data on the second edge/high-to-low transition)
  //see https://deardevices.com/2020/05/31/spi-cpol-cpha/ to understand CPOL/CPHA

  //chip select is negative logic, idles at 1
  //When chip select is set to 0, the chip is then waiting for a value to be written over SPI
  //That value represents the first register that it reads from
  //registers to read from are from addresses 00h to 07h (h = hex, so 0x01, 0x02, etc)
  //00 = configuration register, 01 = MSBs of resistance value, 02 = LSBs of
  //Registers available on datasheet at https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX31865.pdf
  //The chip then automatically increments to read from the next register

  /* Start the read operation. */
  nss = 0; //tell the MAX31865 we want to start reading, waiting for starting address to be written
  /* Tell the MAX31865 that we want to read, starting at register 0. */
  
  
  spi.write( 0x00 ); //start reading values starting at register 00h

  /* Read the MAX31865 registers in the following order:
       Configuration (00)
       RTD (01 = MSBs, 02 = LSBs)
       High Fault Threshold (03 = MSBs, 04 = LSBs)
       Low Fault Threshold (05 = MSBs, 06 = LSBs)
       Fault Status (07) */
    
    this->measured_resistance = 0;

  this->measured_configuration = spi.write( 0x00 ); //read from register 00
    //automatic increment to register 01
  combined_bytes  = spi.write( 0x00 ) << 8; //8 bit value from register 01, bit shifted 8 left
    //automatic increment to register 02, OR with previous bit shifted value to get complete 16 bit value
  combined_bytes |= spi.write( 0x00 );
  //bit 0 of LSB is a fault bit, DOES NOT REPRESENT RESISTANCE VALUE
  //bit shift 16-bit value 1 right to remove fault bit and get complete 15 bit raw resistance reading
  this->measured_resistance = combined_bytes >> 1;
    //high fault threshold
  combined_bytes  = spi.write( 0x00 ) << 8;
  combined_bytes |= spi.write( 0x00 );
  this->measured_high_threshold = combined_bytes >> 1;
    //low fault threshold
  combined_bytes  = spi.write( 0x00 ) << 8;
  combined_bytes |= spi.write( 0x00 );
  this->measured_low_threshold = combined_bytes >> 1;
    //fault status
  this->measured_status = spi.write( 0x00 );

    //set chip select to 1; chip stops incrementing registers when chip select is high; ends read cycle
  nss = 1;

  /* Reset the configuration if the measured resistance is
     zero or a fault occurred. */
  if(    ( this->measured_resistance == 0 )
      || ( this->measured_status != 0 ) )
  {
    //reconfigure( );
    // extra clock cycle causes measured_status to be non-zero, so chip will reconfigure even though it doesn't need to. reconfigure commented out for now.
  }

  return( status( ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Background:*

I took a look at the entire implementation of the MAX31865_RTD class and the thing I find "troubling" is that a MAX31865_RTD instance creates its own SPI instance on construction. If you create multiple instances of this MAX31865_RTD class then there will be a separate SPI instance created and initialized for each of these.

If you have 8 of these chips and you create 8 separate MAX31865_RTD instances to provide one for each of your chips then this also creates 8 SPI instances that all point to the same physical SPI device of the microcontroller.

*The problem:*

When you call the read_all function on your MAX31865_RTD instance it in turn calls the SPI write functions (as seen in the code you provided). But digging deeper in the call chain you will eventually find that the code of the SPI write method (and others as well) is written in a way that it assumes that there can be multiple SPI instances that are using the same SPI hardware with different parameters (frequency, word length, etc...). In order to actually use the SPI hardware, the SPI class instance must first take ownership of the hardware if it does not have it yet. To do this it "acquires" the hardware for itself which basically means that it reconfigures the SPI hardware to the frequency and word length and mode that this particular SPI instance was set to (This happens regardless of the fact that every instance is set to the same parameters. They don't know about each other. They just see the fact that they have lost ownership and thus have to reacquire it and they also automatically assume that the settings are to be restored.). And this frequency (= clock) reinitialization is the reason that your clock is having a weird artefact/glitch on it. Each time you call the read_all on a different MAX31865_RTD instance the SPI instance of that instance will have to do an acquire (because they steal the ownership from each other on each read_all call) and it will make the clock behave weird.

*Why it works if you only have one device:*

Because when you have one and only one MAX31865_RTD instance then it has only one SPI instance which is the sole "owner" of the SPI hardware. So no-one is stealing the ownership on each turn. Which means that it does not have to re-acquire it on every read_all call. So in that case the SPI hardware is not reinitialized every time. So you don't get the weird clock pulse and everything works as intended.

*My proposed solution #1:*

I propose that you change the implementation of the read_all method.
If the version of the SPI class that you use has the select method, then add the

```
spi.select();
```

line just before pulling the chip select (nss) low. Basically add the line above this block:

```
/* Start the read operation. */
nss = 0;
```

If there is no select function, then just add a

```
spi.write(0x00);
```

line in the same place instead of the line with the select.

In essence both of the proposed lines just force the acquire (and the accompanying clock glitch) before the chip select line is asserted. So by the time the chip select is pulled low and the actual data is being written the SPI instance already has ownership and the write methods will not trigger an acquire (nor the clock glitch).

*My proposed solution #2:*

Another solution is to modify the MAX31865_RTD class to use an SPI instance reference and provide that reference through its constructor. That way you can create one SPI instance explicitly and provide this same SPI instance to all your MAX31865_RTD instances at construction. Now since all of your MAX31865_RTD instances are using a reference to the same and only SPI instance, the SPI hardware ownership never changes since there is only one SPI class instance that is using it. Thus the hardware is never reconfigured and the glitch never happens. I would prefer this solution since it is less of a workaround.

*My proposed solution #3:*

You could also modify the MAX31865_RTD class to have a "setter" for the nss (= chip select) pin. That way, you could have only one MAX31865_RTD instance for all your 8 devices and only change the nss pin before addressing the next device. Since there is only one MAX31865_RTD instance then there is only one SPI instance which also solves the ownership issue and since no re-acquisition has to be made then no glitch will be triggered.

And of-course there can be any number of other ways to fix this knowing the reason of the problem.

Hope this helps in solving your issue.